# IntelliSense hints for VisualStudio Code doesn't show what it should

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, classname, hint

Hi I started to watch an online tutorial for JavaScript lessons and the teacher uses good libraries so he is able to see IntelliSense hints while he is typing. The thing is I am not able to see the same hints as he is showing.

I would like to know why my VS Code cannot show the same hints as it is shown in the video tutorial.

*I did comment under the tutorial, but I do not expect that it will be answered soon, or ever, as it is usually at YT free tutorials. And my comments are disappearing.*

The tutorial is here with the correct timestamp to check what I am talking about.
https://youtu.be/jx5hdo50a2M?t=1086

For this example he is writing the
className="underline text-3xl"
and under the cursor he can pick the offered text-3xl expression, and even see what font size it is.

And here I am providing two screenshots of what his IntelliSense offers to him, and what I can see as hints for myself.

https://ibb.co/TW64RtB

https://ibb.co/QcS6rq4

So as you can see on those screens my hints are "*e-text*" or "*e-underline*" but it should be just underline or "*text*" and then "*text-3xl*" options with more rich info hints.

**Am I calling it correctly by saying these are the IntelliSense hints?**

**Do I have to turn something on?**

**Is there a way to make my VS Code to show the same stuff inside IntelliSense hints as he does have?**

**If yes then, does anybody know how to do it?**

If I am overstepping the rules of this web page, then I apologize. I do not know where to ask those kinds of questions.

Thanks in advance for any help.

PS>
I did everything that he did in exact order and still I do not have those hints. So it may be the case that he does have some extensions installed that he didn't mention.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, This one is actually a trivial one.

The reason why I am not seeing the correct hints is because the Tailwind Extension has to be installed in VS Code. After adding this extension, it works perfectly.

How did I found? I got the answer from the creator of the tutorial.

Thanks for it again, Adrian.